# Generating a List Class in Python

Tags: python, list

I am having some problems generating a list for a class in Python.  I know there is something simple I'm overlooking, but I just can't figure it out.

My basic code so far:

```
class Test:
    def  __init__(self,test):
        self.__test = test
```

My problem is that if I enter

```
t = Test([1,3,5])
```

things will work just fine, but if I add

```
t = Test()
```

I get an error that I didn't enter enough parameters.

I've tried adding

```
def __init__(self,test=[])
```

as a default parameter, which sort of works, but then I don't have unique lists.

I've been looking all over and I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with unique lists?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Since you use a double-leading underscore name for your attribute, it's probably worth pointing out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165883/python-object-attributes-methodology-for-access/166098#166098

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but you probably want to use `None` as a default:

```
class Test:
    def  __init__(self,test=None):
        if test is None:
            self.__test = []
        else:
            self.__test = test
```

Comment: Your two branches are a little lopsided. Either assign to `self.__test` in the `is None` branch as well, or just do the assignment after the `if` without an `else`.

Comment: This is where I was having trouble, I tried something similar, but wasn't using 'None' as the default for test.  This fixed my program right up.  Thanks a ton to everyone for the help and extra reading!

Comment: FYI: Personally, I prefer Thomas Wouters' answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following idiom:

```
class Test:
    def  __init__(self,test=None):
        self.__test = test if test is not None else []
```

Comment: @Thomas Wouters: I figured some people might feel that way.  That's why I'm leaving my answer as-is.

Comment: I'm not sure what's unclear about "yuck, ternary expression". I don't like the use of the ternary expression there. (Or, in fact, anywhere.)

Comment: @Thomas, so you didn't use it in your answer. I find it entirely appropriate and readable.

Comment: I agree that it's perfectly readable, and I think it's a poor reason for a down vote.

Comment: Readability of code is important to me, so I *did* downvote -- I find the other answer (that isn't mine) to be better. Fortunately, differences of opinion are why we have sites like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Default arguments are evaluated once, when the function is defined, so when you do:

```
def __init__(self, test=[]):
```

the 'test' list is shared between all calls to `__init__` that don't specify the `test` argument. What you want is commonly expressed so:

```
def __init__(self, test=None):
    if test is None:
        test = []
```

This creates a new list for each invocation where `test` is not passed an argument (or when it is passed `None`, obviously.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I knew that's what was happening, I just didn't know the proper way to alleviate that problem.  I appreciate it greatly!