# basic inheritance (in python)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

users,

I have a basic question concerning inheritance (in python). I have two classes and one of them is inherited from the other like

```
class   p:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.pname  = name

class   c(p):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.cname  = name
```

Is there any possibility that I can create a parent object and several child objects which refer to the SAME parent object? It should work like that that the parent object contains several variables and whenever I access the corresponding variables from a child I actually access the variable form the parent. I.e. if I change it for one child it is changed also for all other childes and the data are only stored once in memory (and not copied for each child...)

Thank you in advance.

Here is a possible workaround which I do not consider as so nice

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.pname = name

class C:
    def __init__(self, name,pobject):
        self.pobject = pobject
        self.cname = name
```

Is this really the state of the art or do there exist other concepts?

Sebastian

Thank you all for helping me, also with the name conventions :) But I am still not very satisfied. Maybe I give a more advanced example to stress what I really want to do.

```
class P:
    data = "shareddata"
    def __init__(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata 

    def printname(self):
        print self.name 

class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
```

Now I can do the following

```
In [33]: c1 = test.C("name1")

In [34]: c2 = test.C("name2")

In [35]: c1.printname()
name1

In [36]: c2.printname()
name2

In [37]: c1.data
Out[37]: 'shareddata'

In [38]: c2.data
Out[38]: 'shareddata'
```

And this is so far exactly what I want. There is a variable name which is different for every child and the parent class accesses the individual variables. Normal inheritance.
Then there is the variable data which comes from the parent class and every child access it. However, now the following does not work any more

```
In [39]: c1.data = "tst"

In [40]: c2.data
Out[40]: 'shareddata'

In [41]: c1.data
Out[41]: 'tst'
```

I want the change in c1.data to affect also c2.data since I want the variable to be shared, somehow a global variable of this parent class.

And more than that. I also want to create different instances of P, each having its own data variable. And when I create a new C object I want to specify from which P object data should be inhetited i.e. shared....

UPDATE:

remark to the comment of  @eyquem: Thanks for this, it is going into the direction I want. However, now the `__class__.pvar` is shared among all objects of the class. What I want is that several instances of P may have a different pvar. Lets assume P1 has pvar=1 and P2 has pvar=2. Then I want to create children C1a, C1b, C1c which are related to P1, i.e. if I say C1a.pvar it should acess pvar from P1. Then I create C2a, C2b, C2c and if I access i.e. C2b.pvar I want to access pvar from P2. Since the class C inherits pvar from the class P pvar is known to C. My naive idea is that if I create a new instance of C I should be able to specify which (existing) P object should be used as the parent object and not to create a completely new P object as it is done when calling `P.__init__` inside of the `__init__` of C... It sounds simple to me, maybe I forget something...

UPDATE:

So I found [this discussion](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t356880-can-you-create-an-instance-of-a-subclass-with-an-existing-instance-of-the-base-class.html) which is pretty much my question

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

The method .**class**._*subclasses*_ seems to be not existing any more..

UPDATE:

Here is onother link:

[link to discussion](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/834541-using-existing-instance-parent)

There it is solved by copying. But I do not want to copy the parent class since I would like that it exists only once...

UPDATE:

Sorry for leaving the discussion yesterday, I am a bit ill... And thank you for the posts! I will now read through them. I thought about it a bit more and here is a possible solution I found

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar):
        self.pobject    = None
        self._pvar  = pvar

    @property
    def pvar(self):
    if self.pobject != None:
        return  self.pobject.pvar
    else:
            return self._pvar
    @pvar.setter
    def pvar(self,val):
    if self.pobject != None:
        self.pobject.pvar = val
    else:
            self._pvar=val

    def printname(self):
    print self.name


class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject):  #<-- The same default `P()` is 
                                          # used for all instances of `C`, 
                                          # unless pobject is explicitly defined.
    P.__init__(self,None)
        self.name   = name
        self.pobject = pobject


p1  = P("1")
p2  = P("2")


c1a = C("c1a",p1)
c1b = C("c1b",p1)
c1c = C("c1c",p1)
c2a = C("c2a",p2)
c2b = C("c2b",p2)
c2c = C("c2c",p2)


print   id(c1a.pvar)
print   id(c1b.pvar)
print   id(c1c.pvar)
print   id(c2a.pvar)
print   id(c2b.pvar)
print   id(c2c.pvar)
print   id(p1.pvar)
print   id(p2.pvar)

print   id(c1a.name)
print   id(c1b.name)
print   id(c1c.name)
print   id(c2a.name)
print   id(c2b.name)
print   id(c2c.name)
```

It is a bit cumbersome and I hope that there is a simpler way to achieve this. But it has the feature that pvar is only mentioned in the class P and the class C does not know about pvar as it should be according to my understanding of inheritance. Nevertheless when I create a new instance of C I can specify an existing instance of P which will be stored in the variable pobject. When the variable pvar is accessed actually pvar of the P-instance stored in this variable is accessed...

The output is given by

```
3078326816
3078326816
3078326816
3074996544
3074996544
3074996544
3078326816
3074996544
156582944
156583040
156583200
156583232
156583296
156583360
```

I will read now through your last comments,

all the best, Sebastian

UPDATE:

I think the most elegant way would be the following (which DOES NOT work)

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar):
        self.pvar   = pvar

    def printname(self):
        print self.name


class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject):  
        P = pobject
        self.name   = name
```

I think python should allow for this...

UPDATE:

Ok, now I found a way to achieve this, due to the explanations by eyquem. But Since this is really a hack there should be an official version for the same...

```
def replaceinstance(parent,child):
    for item in parent.__dict__.items():
        child.__dict__.__setitem__(item[0],item[1])
        print item

class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar):
        self.pvar   = pvar

    def printname(self):
    print self.name


class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject):
    P.__init__(self,None)
    replaceinstance(pobject,self)
        self.name   = name



p1  = P("1")
p2  = P("2")


c1a = C("c1a",p1)
c1b = C("c1b",p1)
c1c = C("c1c",p1)
c2a = C("c2a",p2)
c2b = C("c2b",p2)
c2c = C("c2c",p2)


print   id(c1a.pvar)
print   id(c1b.pvar)
print   id(c1c.pvar)
print   id(c2a.pvar)
print   id(c2b.pvar)
print   id(c2c.pvar)
print   id(p1.pvar)
print   id(p2.pvar)

print   id(c1a.name)
print   id(c1b.name)
print   id(c1c.name)
print   id(c2a.name)
print   id(c2b.name)
print   id(c2c.name)
```

the output is the same as above

```
3077745184
3077745184
3077745184
3074414912
3074414912
3074414912
3077745184
3074414912
144028416
144028448
144028480
144028512
144028544
144028576
```

UPDATE: Even if the id's seem to be right, the last code does not work as is clear from this test

```
c1a.pvar    = "newpvar1"

print   c1a.pvar
print   c1b.pvar
print   c1c.pvar
print   c2a.pvar
print   c2b.pvar
print   c2c.pvar
print   p1.pvar
print   p2.pvar
```

it has the output

```
newpvar1
1
1
2
2
2
1
2
```

However the version I posted first works:

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar):
        self.pobject    = None
        self._pvar  = pvar

    @property
    def pvar(self):
    if self.pobject != None:
        return  self.pobject.pvar
    else:
            return self._pvar
    @pvar.setter
    def pvar(self,val):
    if self.pobject != None:
        self.pobject.pvar = val
    else:
            self._pvar=val

    def printname(self):
    print self.name


class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject):  #<-- The same default `P()` is 
                                          # used for all instances of `C`, 
                                          # unless pobject is explicitly defined.
    P.__init__(self,None)
        self.name   = name
        self.pobject = pobject


p1  = P("1")
p2  = P("2")


c1a = C("c1a",p1)
c1b = C("c1b",p1)
c1c = C("c1c",p1)
c2a = C("c2a",p2)
c2b = C("c2b",p2)
c2c = C("c2c",p2)


print   id(c1a.pvar)
print   id(c1b.pvar)
print   id(c1c.pvar)
print   id(c2a.pvar)
print   id(c2b.pvar)
print   id(c2c.pvar)
print   id(p1.pvar)
print   id(p2.pvar)

print   id(c1a.name)
print   id(c1b.name)
print   id(c1c.name)
print   id(c2a.name)
print   id(c2b.name)
print   id(c2c.name)




print   "testing\n"

c1a.printname()
c1b.printname()
c1c.printname()
c2a.printname()
c2b.printname()
c2c.printname()


print   "\n"
c1a.name = "c1anewname"
c2b.name = "c2bnewname"


c1a.printname()
c1b.printname()
c1c.printname()
c2a.printname()
c2b.printname()
c2c.printname()


print "pvar\n"

print   c1a.pvar
print   c1b.pvar
print   c1c.pvar
print   c2a.pvar
print   c2b.pvar
print   c2c.pvar
print   p1.pvar
print   p2.pvar

print "\n"
c1a.pvar    = "newpvar1"

print   c1a.pvar
print   c1b.pvar
print   c1c.pvar
print   c2a.pvar
print   c2b.pvar
print   c2c.pvar
print   p1.pvar
print   p2.pvar

print "\n"
c2c.pvar    = "newpvar2"

print   c1a.pvar
print   c1b.pvar
print   c1c.pvar
print   c2a.pvar
print   c2b.pvar
print   c2c.pvar
print   p1.pvar
print   p2.pvar
```

with the output

```
3077745184
3077745184
3077745184
3074414912
3074414912
3074414912
3077745184
3074414912
144028416
144028448
144028480
144028512
144028544
144028576
testing

c1a
c1b
c1c
c2a
c2b
c2c


c1anewname
c1b
c1c
c2a
c2bnewname
c2c
pvar

1
1
1
2
2
2
1
2


newpvar1
newpvar1
newpvar1
2
2
2
newpvar1
2


newpvar1
newpvar1
newpvar1
newpvar2
newpvar2
newpvar2
newpvar1
newpvar2
```

Does anybody know why it is like that? I probably do not understand the internal way python works with this `__dict__` so well...

Comment: Please use Upper Case Names for your Class Names.

Comment: CamelCaseNames for class names and underscore_names for instances.

Comment: @r6d9 _Lets assume P1 has pvar=1 and P2 has pvar=2._  and  _to specify which (existing) P object should be used_ => so there are several classes P ??!?

Comment: @eyquem: I added a solution (which is not so nice in my eyes) which has the behavior I want. But I think one should be able to do this much nicer....

Comment: There is an obvious way to do this -- using a properly

Comment: -1: You've made a simple question into an unreadable mess.  Please edit the question so that it is exactly one question with exactly one answer.  Every nuanced thought is not part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

> It should work like that that the parent object contains several variables and whenever I access the corresponding variables from a child I actually access the variable form the parent. I.e. if I change it for one child it is changed also for all other childes and the data are only stored once in memory (and not copied for each child...)

That's not inheritance.

That's a completely different concept.

Your "shared variables" are simply objects that can be mutated and have references in other objects.  Nothing interesting.

Inheritance is completely different from this.

Comment: Q. Is it possible to make direct Perl-calls from HTML without having to press any buttons ?? A. Is it possible to grow vegetables from a painting, without becoming Wednesday first? [Abigail] (Taken from: http://www.utdallas.edu/~asimpson/misc/funny/abigailisms).

Answer (score 1):

I think your workaround is doable; You could use properties to make access to `P`'s attributes easier:

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,name='default',pvar=1):
        self.pname  = name
        self.pvar=pvar

class C(object):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject=P()):  #<-- The same default `P()` is 
                                          # used for all instances of `C`, 
                                          # unless pobject is explicitly defined.
        self.cname  = name
        self.pobject=pobject
    @property
    def pvar(self):
        return self.pobject.pvar
    @pvar.setter
    def pvar(self,val):
        self.pobject.pvar=val

c1=C('1')
c2=C('2')
```

`c1` and `c2` share the same `pobject`:

```
print(c1.pvar)
# 1
c1.pvar=2
```

Notice that changing `pvar` through `c1` changes `c2.pvar`:

```
print(c2.pvar)
# 2
```

`c3` has a different `pobject`:

```
c3=C('3',P())
print(c3.pvar)
# 1
```

---

Regarding OOP design for the psychology experiment (mentioned in the comments):

```
import Image

class Picture(object):
    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.image=Image.open(filename)       

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        # other vital statistics associated with people as individuals here

class Trial(object):
    # A trial is composed of one person, one picture, and the places they look
    def __init__(self,person,picture,locations):
        self.person=person
        self.picture=picture
        self.locations = locations
    # put methods for analyzing where the person looked here
```

A `Picture` is certainly not a `Person`, nor vice versa. And the same goes for `Trial`s. So none of these classes should inherit from each other.

Each of these classes have a public (and maybe a private) interface.
Public methods and attributes should be freely accessible from other classes.
So given a `Trial` instance, `t`, the image should be accessible through `t.picture.image`. As long as you are only accessing public attributes and methods, then everything should be fine.

For convenience, you can use `properties` to link attributes to component-attributes. For example:

```
class Trial(object):
    ...
    @property
    def image(self):
        return self.picture.image
```

But to short-cut this by making, say, `Trial` a subclass of `Picture` would be contrary to fundamental OOP design principles.

Comment: @unutbu: Thank you for this hint. But is it possible to have now several P objects witch all have a different value of pvar? When I create a new instance of C I would like to specify from which P-object this should be created and all C objects created from the same P object should share the same pvar....

Comment: @unutbu: +1 almost perfect, I would just make self.pobject `self.__pobject` to hide it.

Comment: @ubutbu: Thank you for this example, it looks already good. However, what I do not like about this way of programming is that pvar really belongs to the class P and now we are writing methods to read and write it in the class C... So somehow we are spoiling the concept of OOP and therefore I thought that there is maybe a different solution...

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: Thanks, Paulo. I tend not to use double-underscores. See the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165883/python-object-attributes-methodology-for-access/166098#166098 for why.

Comment: @r6d9: What I've coded is an example of the Delegation design pattern. See http://www.lecturefox.com/blog/python-design-patterns-by-alex-martelli.

Comment: @unutbu: I will have a look at that. But is it possible to achieve the same by just telling the class C that It should access pvar from the given class pobject? Then all the code inside of class C related to pvar would not be necessary...

Comment: @r6d9: You could use `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` instead of defining properties, but `__getattr__` has some surprising pitfalls (http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html), so I prefer explicit properties over `__getattr__` even if it is more verbose.

Comment: @r6d9: I might have been mistaken when I referenced Alex Martelli's video lectures on design patterns as a source for info an the Delegation design pattern (at least I wasn't able to find it there quickly). They are still a great resource, but for an example of Delegation in Python you might just glance here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Python

Comment: @unutbu: Thanks for the hints, I will have a look. See also the link to the discussion I found in the web. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @r6d9: I don't think dynamically changing class via `__class__` is the way to go here. That's too exotic for me, and what would you change the class to? You have at the moment only two classes...

Comment: @r6d9: One thing to keep in mind is: Instances of `C` can inherit from the class `P`, but they can never inherit from instances of `P`. So if you have different instances of `P`, there is no way for instances of `C` to peek at their instance attributes, unless you make the instance of `P` a component of the instance of `C`. There is a different way to approach this however -- by making `pvar` a property instead of a bare value. I'm not sure if you'll like this, but it does move `P` related things out of the `C` class. I'll edit my answer above to show what I mean.

Comment: @r6d9: Above, "to peek at their instance attributes" should really read "to inherit `P`'s instance attributes". Peeking is possible, inheriting is not.

Comment: @r6d9 At the beginning of your question there were only P, C, and instances of C: _"I have two classes and one of them is inheritated from the other like"_ . Now you want _"several P objects witch all have a different value of pvar? When I create a new instance of C I would like to specify from which P-object this should be created"_ . It seems to me that changing the question complicates the way to answer. Finally, wouldn't a metaclass be what you need ?

Comment: @unutbu: I added a possible solution to my question. What do you think about that? Is there an easier way to accomplish this behavior?

Comment: @r6d9: I looked at your proposed code (the one with `self.pobject` in `P`). Having `self`, an instance of `P` or `C`, have an attribute `self.pobject` which is itself an instance of `P` seems very weird to me. I do not believe this is the right way to do this. I know I am biased, but I like my way better :).

Comment: @unutbu: I just think that it is nicer to have everything related to pvar put only into the P class. In your code pvar is in both classes which spoils the concept of inheritance in my eyes. What do you think about the second code I proposed? I think for the call to replaceinstance there should be a keyword in python or an "official" way. Then I would be very satisfied. What do you think?

Comment: @r6d9: One of the first things that needs to be settled is: Is `C` a `P`? Is `C` a specialized type of `P`? The fact that you seem to need to pass an instance of `P` into `C.__init__` suggests that `C` is not really a subclass of `P`. Instead `C` has a `P`. This leads to the idea that we need composition here, not inheritance.

Comment: @unutbu: Ok, I REALLY want C to be a specialized version of P. That means I really want C to have variables, methods, and so force from P. Lets say I create c1 = C(). Now I do not now which variables the class P has. However I do know that C inherits from P. Now I also have an object p1 = P(). And now I want that all variables from c1 which it inherited from the class P now reference to the variables of this given object p1.  So if a procedure knows that P has a variable pvar because it knows the class P it should be able to reference c1.pvar. And then it should access p1.pvar...

Comment: @r6d9: I hear you, I think I understand what you want, but I don't think there is a nice way to achieve that. Your solution works, but *feels* wrong to me. If that is the only way to satisfy your requirements, then I'd urge you to re-evaluate your requirements, think more broadly about your overall problem and search for a more beautiful way to solve it. Sorry, I can't think of any better alternatives.

Comment: @unutbu: Thank you very much for your help and your patience, I just thought that this what I want to do should be something very common in oop. Maybe it is not and maybe It is not needed because there are better alternatives. But I still think that the concept behind that what I want to achieve is worth being implemented inside a language as python. Let me explain the situation in more detail

Comment: @unutbu: I have to process data from an experiment in psychology. People see a picture and their eyes are tracked. So I have a picture which is shown to all the persons. Then I have for every person data where they look. So I want a class which contains the picture and methods how to analyze where the people look, say P. This should be the parent class. Then For every person I want a class containing the data say D. D should be inherited from P that I can simply access the methods from D and I want D.pic to return the picture. But I do not want that any D contains a copy of the picture...

Comment: @r6d9 I am interested by your problem. It makes me think about the working of classes, it is a good exercise to train oneself, and it's worthwhile to sharpen one's ability to diagnose if the manner to treat a problem is justified or not. I feel that your way isn't a good one, but I can't explain precisely why. I tried quantities of ideas, but i reached only dead-ends. I don't know what to do more but I will continue to think about the problem.

Comment: @r6d9 The reason of the difficulty is that an instance **p1** of class **P** must share the value of its attribute **pvar** with the values of the identically named attributes of several instances **c** of subclass of **P** = **C**. So there are interferences between changing the values after instanciation and processes during instantiation. I tried to use **\_\_getattr__** , **\_\_getattribute__** and **\_\_setattr__** to redirect **pvar** of a **c** towards **pvar** of the common **p** instance, but I didn't succeed to disconnect the processes of changing and instantiation

Comment: @eyquem: From the implementation point of view I think it should be easy. If I create a new instance of a child class, I have to allocate memory for the variables in the child class and also for those inherited from the parent class. If I want to access a variable from the parent class than python has to map the name of the variable somehow to a pointer which points to the actual data in memory. And this pointer could simply point to the data in an existing instance of the parent class... So from my naive perspective the implementation should be easy. But maybe such a feature would be prone

Comment: to errors and the developer decided not to implement it as there are also no pointers in python...

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is right, your question is more about namespaces and references than about inheritance.

All variables in Python are references, and all object instance is a namespace. So you can do:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x  = x

class Shared(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value  = value

# instances:
>>> shared1 = Shared(1)
>>> shared2 = Shared(2)
>>> c1 = C(shared1)
>>> c2 = C(shared1)
>>> c3 = C(shared2)
>>> c4 = C(shared2)
# c1 and c2 sharing a reference to shared1
>>> c1.x.value
1
>>> c2.x.value
1
# change c2.x will reflect on c1 
>>> c2.x.value = 3
>>> c1.x.value
3
# but not on c3, because shared1 and shared2 are distinct namespaces
>>> c3.x.value
2
```

UPDATE:

But watch out, it is easy to make a mistake:

```
>>> c4.x = 4
>>> c3.x.value
2
>>> c4.x.value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'
>>>
```

I think the state of the art would be using [properties](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) to hide the [`__shared_instance`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) in a private instance variable - so you can use c1.x instead of c1.x.value and avoid a typo like the example above.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: I think this is exactly what I have suggested as a work around. If this is the state of the art I will do it like this. Thank you for confirming that!

Comment: @Paulo Scardine: See my comment to unutbu's answer, what do you think?

Comment: @r6d9: unutbu's answer is how to do it in Python. IMHO it is not ugly or workarround, and it is away better then using global variables.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine  There is no inheritance in this code. It's a game with assignations and underlying dictionnaries/namespaces. I will do an answer about this, later.

Comment: @eyquem: I don't think inheritance is a good strategy to achieve what he wants.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine But the fact is that he does want inheritance, and as we don't know exactly what is his goal, we can't affirm that his intention is in a wrong way and that he must not use inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I am lost in all these diverse answers.

But I think that what you need is expressed in the following code:

```
class P:
    pvar=1                    # <--- class attribute
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.cname  = name

class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.cname  = name


c1=C('1')
c2=C('2')

print
print "C.pvar ==",C.pvar,'  id(C.pvar) ==',id(C.pvar)
print "c1.pvar==",c1.pvar,'  id(c1.pvar)==',id(c1.pvar)
print "c2.pvar==",c2.pvar,'  id(c2.pvar)==',id(c2.pvar)

print
C.pvar = [1,2]
print "instruction   C.pvar = [1,2]   executed"
print "C.pvar ==",C.pvar,'  id(C.pvar) ==',id(C.pvar)
print "c1.pvar==",c1.pvar,'  id(c1.pvar)==',id(c1.pvar)
print "c2.pvar==",c2.pvar,'  id(c2.pvar)==',id(c2.pvar)

print
c2.__class__.pvar = 'sun'
print "instruction   c2.__class__.pvar = 'sun'   executed"
print "C.pvar ==",C.pvar,'  id(C.pvar) ==',id(C.pvar)
print "c1.pvar==",c1.pvar,'  id(c1.pvar)==',id(c1.pvar)
print "c2.pvar==",c2.pvar,'  id(c2.pvar)==',id(c2.pvar)

print
c2.pvar = 145
print "instruction   c2.pvar = 145   executed"
print "C.pvar ==",C.pvar,'  id(C.pvar) ==',id(C.pvar)
print "c1.pvar==",c1.pvar,'  id(c1.pvar)==',id(c1.pvar)
print "c2.pvar==",c2.pvar,'  id(c2.pvar)==',id(c2.pvar)
```

result

```
C.pvar == 1   id(C.pvar) == 10021768
c1.pvar== 1   id(c1.pvar)== 10021768
c2.pvar== 1   id(c2.pvar)== 10021768

instruction   C.pvar = [1,2]   executed
C.pvar == [1, 2]   id(C.pvar) == 18729640
c1.pvar== [1, 2]   id(c1.pvar)== 18729640
c2.pvar== [1, 2]   id(c2.pvar)== 18729640

instruction   c2.__class__.pvar = 'sun'   executed
C.pvar == sun   id(C.pvar) == 18579136
c1.pvar== sun   id(c1.pvar)== 18579136
c2.pvar== sun   id(c2.pvar)== 18579136

instruction   c2.pvar = 145   executed
C.pvar == sun   id(C.pvar) == 18579136
c1.pvar== sun   id(c1.pvar)== 18579136
c2.pvar== 145   id(c2.pvar)== 10022024
```

I mean that what you must know is that to change , through an instruction implying directly the name of an instance (and not through a change implying only the parent class's name) the class attribute **pvar** while it continues to be shared by all the **P** 's instances, you must write

```
c2.__class__.pvar = something
```

and not

```
c2.pvar =something
```

Note that C is a class effectively inheriting from a parent class P

Comment: @r6d9 I underligned that this code has inheritance in it , contrary to the Paulo Scardine's answer

Answer (score 0):

One thing you must know as a base of the understanding of  functionning of classes and instances:

> A class instance has a namespace
>   implemented as a dictionary which is
>   the **first place in which attribute
>   references are searched**.
>
> When an attribute is not found there,
>   and the instance’s class has an
>   attribute by that name, the search
>   continues with the class attributes.
>
> http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy

In the second sentence, I don't exactly understand the meaning of "by that name" , but I understand of the global that an attribute is searched first in the namespace of an instance and then in the namespace of its type.

In the following code :

- For class `P` and instance `c` :

the name **'dataclass'** and object `dataclass` really belong to the `P` class's namespace and only APPARENTLY belong to the `c` instance's namespace: when `c.dataclass` is called , that's in fact `c.__class__.dataclass` that is attained, by the course of search described above.

- But in an instance `cc` of the class `PP` , the name **'data'** , which belongs to the `P` class's namespace, is assigned (binded) by the definition occuring in `__init__()` to a new `data` object created in the `c` instance's namespace.

Hence, the only solution to obtain the class's `data`'s value is to call it by its real reference, either `PP.data` or `cc.__class__.data`  .

```
class   P:
    dataclass    = "shareddata"

    def __init__(self,newdata):
        self.data   = newdata

    def printname(self):
        print   self.name

c = P(1)

print 'P.__dict__.keys()==',P.__dict__.keys()
print 'c.__dict__.keys()==',c.__dict__.keys()
print  
print 'c.data==',c.data
print 'c.dataclass==',c.dataclass


print 

class   PP:
    data    = "shareddata"

    def __init__(self,newdata):
        self.data   = newdata

    def printname(self):
        print   self.name

cc = PP(2)
print 'PP.__dict__.keys()==',PP.__dict__.keys()
print 'cc.__dict__.keys()==',cc.__dict__.keys()
print
print 'cc.data==',cc.data
print 'PP.data==',PP.data
print 'cc.__class__.data==',cc.__class__.data
```

result

```
P.__dict__.keys()== ['dataclass', '__module__', 'printname', '__init__', '__doc__']
c.__dict__.keys()== ['data']

c.data== 1
c.dataclass== shareddata

PP.__dict__.keys()== ['__module__', 'data', 'printname', '__init__', '__doc__']
cc.__dict__.keys()== ['data']

cc.data== 2
PP.data== shareddata
cc.__class__.data== shareddata
```

.

Note:

> **dir([object])**
>
> With an argument, attempt to return a
>   list of valid attributes for that
>   object.
>
> If the object does not provide
>   **dir**(), the function tries its best to gather information from the
>   object’s **dict** attribute, if
>   defined, and from its type object.
>
> The default dir() mechanism behaves
>   differently with different types of
>   objects, as it attempts to produce the
>   most relevant, rather than complete,
>   information:
>
> •If the object is a type or class
>   object, the list contains the names of
>   its attributes, and recursively of the
>   attributes of its bases.
>
> •Otherwise, the list contains the
>   object’s attributes’ names, the names
>   of its class’s attributes, and
>   recursively of the attributes of its
>   class’s base classes.
>
> http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir

.

Hence, the use of `dir(ob)` to display the attributes of the object `ob` is a trap because it display more attributes than the ones belonging strictly to the object.

In other words, **__dict__** is the real thing, while **dir()** gives a dashboard, in a sense.

Comment: Thank you for outlining the details of the instance/object concept. I used this for a new implementation, see above.

Answer (score 0):

r6d9, please, when you write an update, you should put the date and hour by the word UPDATE. It begins to be complcated to follow all that

.

.

Concerning this code of you:

```
def replaceinstance(parent,child):
    for item in parent.__dict__.items():
        child.__dict__.__setitem__(item[0],item[1])
        print item

class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar):
        self.pvar   = pvar
    def printname(self):
        print self.name

class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject):
        P.__init__(self,None)
        replaceinstance(pobject,self)
        self.name   = name
```

it can be replaced by this one:

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar):
        self.pvar   = pvar
    def printname(self):
        print self.name

class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject):
        P.__init__(self,None)
        self.pvar = pobject.pvar
        self.name   = name
```

but it seems to simple

Comment: Sorry for not putting the date, it is really now a bit a mess.... I think that your code also invalidates the oop principle that the class C should not know that the class P has a variable pvar. What do you think?

Comment: @r6d9 I think that I don't know what is the principle of OO, apart from the fact that an instance gather together data in fields and methods to process the data. Also: _Methods may reference global names in the same way as ordinary functions. The global scope associated with a method is the module containing the class definition. (The class itself is never used as a global scope.) While one rarely encounters a good reason for using global data in a method, there are many legitimate uses of the global scope_ (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks)

Comment: @r6d9 By the way, **P.__init__(self,None)** requires **C** to be aware that **P** has an **\_\_init__ function.

Comment: Thank you for working so much on the problem. I am not sure whether I am right but I think that OO means also that a class which inherited from another class must know only a minimum about the parent class. Especially internal structures (as variables which are private to the parent class) should not be "known" to the child class. At least this is what I consider a good design... I think the child class should know and use only a well defined interface to communicate with the parent class if this is necessary and I would consider __init__ to be part of this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a way to do it.

The key point is to abandon the aim to obtain instances **c** with real **pvar** field, because it is impossible:

Since it is the same **_*init*_()** function (the one being in class P) that processes to create the objects **pvar**, it isn't possible to create **pvar** in instances **c** that will points to the **pvar** in an instance **p** to mirror its value and that will also give the possibility to change this value of a **p**'s **pvar** each time a **c**'s **pvar**'s value will change. That makes too much contradictory conditions to verify.

Consequently, since the instances **c** can't have a real **pvar** field, the best is to set up a mechanism controling the creation of ( with **_*setattr*_** ) and access to ( with **_*getattr*_** )  these **c**'s seemingly **pvar** objects to give the illusion that they exist.

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar_arg,foo="^^^ "):
        self.pvar = pvar_arg
        self.cat  = foo
    def printname(self):
        print self.name

class C(P):

    def __init__(self,name,pobject,foo=''):
        self.__dict__['name'] = name
        P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)
        C.dic[name] = pobject

    def __setattr__(self,xn,val):
        if xn!='pvar':
            self.__dict__[xn] = val
        elif self.name in C.dic:
            # During the creation of an instance c,
            # this condition is False because the instruction
            # C.dic[name] = pobject is  written after 
            # P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo).
            # Hence the value of pobject.pvar is preserved,
            # not changed with the value val being None
            # due to P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)
            # that provokes self.pvar = pvar_arg and
            # consequently a call __setattr__(self,'pvar',None)
            C.dic[self.name].pvar = val

    def __getattribute__(self,xn):
        if xn=='pvar':
            return object.__getattribute__(C.dic[self.name],'pvar')
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self,xn)

    dic = {}


p1  = P("1")
p2  = P("2","QZX ")
print '--- p1  = P("1")  and  p2  = P("2","QZX ")  executed ---'
print "p1.__dict__  ==",p1.__dict__
print "p2.__dict__  ==",p2.__dict__
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar

c1a = C("c1a",p1,'sea')
c1b = C("c1b",p1,'mountain')
c1c = C("c1c",p1,'desert')
c2a = C("c2a",p2,'banana')
c2b = C("c2b",p2)
c2c = C("c2c",p2,'pear')
print '\n--- creations of c1a, c1b, c1c, c2a, c2b, c2c executed ---'
print "p1.__dict__  ==",p1.__dict__
print "p2.__dict__  ==",p2.__dict__
print "c1a.__dict__ ==",c1a.__dict__
print "c1b.__dict__ ==",c1b.__dict__
print "c1c.__dict__ ==",c1c.__dict__
print "c2a.__dict__ ==",c2a.__dict__
print "c2b.__dict__ ==",c2b.__dict__
print "c2c.__dict__ ==",c2c.__dict__
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar
print '(c1a.pvar, c1b.pvar, c1c.pvar)==',(c1a.pvar,c1b.pvar,c1c.pvar)
print '(c2a.pvar, c2b.pvar, c2c.pvar)==',(c2a.pvar,c2b.pvar,c2c.pvar)

c1a.pvar = "newpvar1"
print '\n--- c1a.pvar = "newpvar1"  executed ---'
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar
print '(c1a.pvar, c1b.pvar, c1c.pvar)==',(c1a.pvar,c1b.pvar,c1c.pvar)
print '(c2a.pvar, c2b.pvar, c2c.pvar)==',(c2a.pvar,c2b.pvar,c2c.pvar)

c2c.pvar = 45789
print '\n--- c2c.pvar = 45789  executed ---'
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar
print '(c1a.pvar, c1b.pvar, c1c.pvar)==',(c1a.pvar,c1b.pvar,c1c.pvar)
print '(c2a.pvar, c2b.pvar, c2c.pvar)==',(c2a.pvar,c2b.pvar,c2c.pvar)
```

result

```
--- p1  = P("1")  and  p2  = P("2","QZX ")  executed ---
p1.__dict__  == {'cat': '^^^ ', 'pvar': '1'}
p2.__dict__  == {'cat': 'QZX ', 'pvar': '2'}
p1.pvar== 1
p2.pvar== 2

--- creations of c1a, c1b, c1c, c2a, c2b, c2c executed ---
p1.__dict__  == {'cat': '^^^ ', 'pvar': '1'}
p2.__dict__  == {'cat': 'QZX ', 'pvar': '2'}
c1a.__dict__ == {'name': 'c1a', 'cat': '^^^ sea'}
c1b.__dict__ == {'name': 'c1b', 'cat': '^^^ mountain'}
c1c.__dict__ == {'name': 'c1c', 'cat': '^^^ desert'}
c2a.__dict__ == {'name': 'c2a', 'cat': 'QZX banana'}
c2b.__dict__ == {'name': 'c2b', 'cat': 'QZX '}
c2c.__dict__ == {'name': 'c2c', 'cat': 'QZX pear'}
p1.pvar== 1
p2.pvar== 2
(c1a.pvar, c1b.pvar, c1c.pvar)== ('1', '1', '1')
(c2a.pvar, c2b.pvar, c2c.pvar)== ('2', '2', '2')

--- c1a.pvar = "newpvar1"  executed ---
p1.pvar== newpvar1
p2.pvar== 2
(c1a.pvar, c1b.pvar, c1c.pvar)== ('newpvar1', 'newpvar1', 'newpvar1')
(c2a.pvar, c2b.pvar, c2c.pvar)== ('2', '2', '2')

--- c2c.pvar = 45789  executed ---
p1.pvar== newpvar1
p2.pvar== 45789
(c1a.pvar, c1b.pvar, c1c.pvar)== ('newpvar1', 'newpvar1', 'newpvar1')
(c2a.pvar, c2b.pvar, c2c.pvar)== (45789, 45789, 45789)
```

Remarks:

1. the attribute **name** must be defined before the instruction

   ### P.**init**(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)

   because the execution of this instruction calls

   `__setattr__(self,'pvar',"1")` that executes itself the instruction

   `C.dic[self.name].pvar = "1"` when

   `c1a = C("c1a",p1,'sea')` is executed, for example.

   AnHence this call needs **self.name** as key for dic.
2. I introduced **foo** and **cat** to

   justify the need to write the instruction

   ### P.**init**(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)

   otherwise, as no **pvar** is in fact defined into the instances **c** , this instuction wouldn't be useful.
3. There are two situations in which
   `__setattr__` is called: at the creation of an instance, and at the modifications of the attributes of an existing instance. When an instance is created, the value of **pvar** of the instance **p** must remain unaffected by the instruction `C.dic[self.name].pvar = None` . Hence the condition `elif self.name in C.dic:`

   In order that this condition gives a correct result, the instruction `C.dic[name] = pobject` must follow the call to `P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)`

.

EDIT 1

I think it's better to write

```
def __setattr__(self,xn,val):
    if xn=='pvar':
        self.__class__.dic[self.name].pvar = val
```

than

```
def __setattr__(self,xn,val):
    if xn=='pvar':
        C.dic[self.name].pvar = val
```

In the first case, the interpreter has to search for the reference to the **self**'s class **C** ( that is to say under the name **'_*class*_'** ) in the namespace of self.

In the second case, the interpreter  must search for the same reference ( but under the name **'C'**) in the namespace of the level in which classes **P** and **C** are defined.

This second namespace may be  more more  big than the limited namespace of an instance. In the first case, the name **'_*class*_'**  is looked for as a key in the dictionary implementing the self's namespace.
In the second, the name **'C'** is the key searched for in the dictionary of the level inclosing the classes **P** and **C**.

The identity of these two objects can be verified with the function **id()**

.

.

EDIT 2

There is another possibility for the `dic` object: instead of making it a class attribute of the class **C**, it can be defined in the outer scope of the class **C**. If this outer level is a module, then **dic** is a global object.

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar,foo="^^^ "):
        self.pvar   = pvar
        self.cat = foo
    def printname(self):
        print self.name

class C(P):

    def __init__(self,name,pobject,foo=''):
        self.__dict__['name'] = name
        P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)
        dic[name] = pobject

    def __setattr__(self,xn,val):
        if xn!='pvar':
            self.__dict__[xn] = val
        elif self.name in dic:
            # During the creation of an instance c,
            # this condition is False because the instruction
            # dic[name] = pobject is  written after 
            # P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo).
            # Hence the value of pobject.pvar is preserved,
            # not changed with the value val being None
            # due to P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)
            # that provokes self.pvar = pvar_arg and
            # consequently a call __setattr__(self,'pvar',None)
            dic[self.name].pvar = val

    def __getattribute__(self,xn):
        if xn=='pvar':
            return object.__getattribute__(dic[self.name],'pvar')
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self,xn)


dic = {}
```

The result is exactly the same

Doing so, **dic** looses its OOish nature.

.

.

EDIT 3

At last, there is still another way: instead of creating an illusory attribute **pvar** for each instance **c** with help of functions `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` , it is better, according to me, to use a function with the dictionary **dic** as a default argument and that will replace them.

```
class P(object):
    def __init__(self,pvar,foo="^^^ "):
        self.pvar   = pvar
        self.cat = foo
    def printname(self):
        print self.name

class C(P):
    def __init__(self,name,pobject,foo=''):
        P.__init__(self,None,pobject.cat+foo)
        self.__dict__['name'] = name
        del self.pvar
        self.pvar(pobject)

    def pvar(self,x = None,dic = {}):
        if x.__class__==P: # a pobject
            dic[self.name] = x
        elif x: # a value
            dic[self.name].pvar = x
        else: # to return value
            return dic[self.name].pvar

p1  = P("1")
p2  = P("2","QZX ")
print '--- p1  = P("1")  and  p2  = P("2","QZX ")  executed ---'
print "p1.__dict__  ==",p1.__dict__
print "p2.__dict__  ==",p2.__dict__
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar

c1a = C("c1a",p1,'sea')
c1b = C("c1b",p1,'mountain')
c1c = C("c1c",p1,'desert')
c2a = C("c2a",p2,'banana')
c2b = C("c2b",p2)
c2c = C("c2c",p2,'pear')
print '\n--- creations of c1a, c1b, c1c, c2a, c2b, c2c executed ---'
print "p1.__dict__  ==",p1.__dict__
print "p2.__dict__  ==",p2.__dict__
print "c1a.__dict__ ==",c1a.__dict__
print "c1b.__dict__ ==",c1b.__dict__
print "c1c.__dict__ ==",c1c.__dict__
print "c2a.__dict__ ==",c2a.__dict__
print "c2b.__dict__ ==",c2b.__dict__
print "c2c.__dict__ ==",c2c.__dict__
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar
print   '(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())==',(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())
print   '(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())==',(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())

c1a.pvar("newpvar1")
print '\n--- c1a.pvar("newpvar1")  executed ---'
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar
print   '(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())==',(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())
print   '(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())==',(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())

c2c.pvar(45789)
print '\n--- c2c.pvar(45789) ---'
print 'p1.pvar==',p1.pvar
print 'p2.pvar==',p2.pvar
print   '(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())==',(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())
print   '(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())==',(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())
```

Results are the same, only use of c.pvar() is slightly different:

```
--- p1  = P("1")  and  p2  = P("2","QZX ")  executed ---
p1.__dict__  == {'cat': '^^^ ', 'pvar': '1'}
p2.__dict__  == {'cat': 'QZX ', 'pvar': '2'}
p1.pvar== 1
p2.pvar== 2

--- creations of c1a, c1b, c1c, c2a, c2b, c2c executed ---
p1.__dict__  == {'cat': '^^^ ', 'pvar': '1'}
p2.__dict__  == {'cat': 'QZX ', 'pvar': '2'}
c1a.__dict__ == {'cat': '^^^ sea', 'name': 'c1a'}
c1b.__dict__ == {'cat': '^^^ mountain', 'name': 'c1b'}
c1c.__dict__ == {'cat': '^^^ desert', 'name': 'c1c'}
c2a.__dict__ == {'cat': 'QZX banana', 'name': 'c2a'}
c2b.__dict__ == {'cat': 'QZX ', 'name': 'c2b'}
c2c.__dict__ == {'cat': 'QZX pear', 'name': 'c2c'}
p1.pvar== 1
p2.pvar== 2
(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())== ('1', '1', '1')
(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())== ('2', '2', '2')

--- c1a.pvar("newpvar1")  executed ---
p1.pvar== newpvar1
p2.pvar== 2
(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())== ('newpvar1', 'newpvar1', 'newpvar1')
(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())== ('2', '2', '2')

--- c2c.pvar(45789) ---
p1.pvar== newpvar1
p2.pvar== 45789
(c1a.pvar(),c1b.pvar(),c1c.pvar())== ('newpvar1', 'newpvar1', 'newpvar1')
(c2a.pvar(),c2b.pvar(),c2c.pvar())== (45789, 45789, 45789)
```

Note that in this last code **P**'s instances can't be values of **C**'instances because a **pobject** passed to a **c.pvar()** method will never be considered as a value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think you might want to rephrase your question as:

**How can I extend Python's OOP to make inheritance work on the level of objects rather than classes?**

*First off - don't mess with the dicts:*
If you are just copying the entries of the parent dict over to the child-dict, this works for instantiation, but  changes in any of the dicts will not automagically update entries in all the other dicts. Assigning a new value to an attribute will simply create a new reference, so the attribute will not point to the same object any more.

The solution is to tell python to look for the attribute in the right place using some Python magic ...

```
class ProxyMixin (object):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name != 'parent' and hasattr(self.parent, name):
            return getattr(self.parent, name)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        if name != 'parent' and hasattr(self.parent, name):
            setattr(self.parent, name)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self, name, val)
```

(see the [python reference on attribute access](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#attribute-access))

Just add the ProxyMixin to your child class, and you will be fine.

```
class P:
    data = "shared data"
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def printname(self):
        print self.name

class C(P, ProxyMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        if parent:
            ProxyMixin.__init__(self, parent)
```

Now youn can dynamically rewire the parent object at any time using a simple assignment:

```
c.parent = newparent
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your post, I will read about __getattribute__ and __setattr__ and try your code...

Comment: Could you give an example with real values, please.