# python oop polymorphism

Tags: python, oop, polymorphism

I can't understand why this code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 1
    def get_value(self):
        return self.__value

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__( self )
        self.__value = 2

b = B()

print b.get_value()
```

gives 1, but not 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165883/python-object-attributes-methodology-for-access/166098#166098 has a long explanation for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that double underscores are [special](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) in python, and create some modicum of privacy (not enforced, but it mangles the names, which is what is affecting you here).  You should recreate this without the variable being named with double underscores.  Also, you should use `super` instead of calling `A.__init__` explicitly:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.value = 1
...     def get_value(self):
...             return self.value
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...             super(B, self).__init__()
...             self.value = 2
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.get_value()
2
```

For more specifics if you don't want to read the referenced documentation:

If you read the link on "special" above, that paragraph describes the internal name mangling that happens when you use `__`.  The short answer is that `A.get_value()` returns `_A__value`, and setting `self.__value` in `B` actually sets a member variable named `_B__value`, which means that `A.get_value()` never sees it.

You can prove this to yourself by indeed doing something *truly* hinky:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def get_value(self):
...             return self._B__value
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.__value = 2
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> b.get_value()
2
```

Comment: Don't you mean super(A, self).__init__() instead super(B, self).__init__()?

Comment: @scr: Nope. It takes the current class.

Comment: I know that removing underscores brings 2, but why does it return 1 with them??

Comment: If `super(B, self).__init__()` is omitted, `b.get_value()` still returns 2. Why the need for `super()`?

Answer (score 3):

`self.__value = 1` creates 'private' field, which is invisible for children in a such way.

Use single underscore for 'protected' fields.

E.g. `self._value = 1`

When you creates field with name started with double underscore, Python makes some modification on it before adding to object's `__dict__`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__value = 1
...     def get_value(self):
...         return self.__value
...
>>> A().__dict__
{'_A__value': 1}
```

That is why `__value` field is not visible in child object.

Comment: Python has neither "private" nor "protected"; both are just conventions, one of which the compiler acts upon.

Comment: @Ignacio sure, that is why I enclosed these words in quotes.